# App Harbor "Couldn't pick a single solution file" build error

Tags: github, appharbor

I have a GitHub Repository with more that one solution (One for AppHarbor and the other for Windows Azure, separate but interdependent apps.)

How can I push to AppHarbor and Identify which SLN is "primary" or "selected" with respect to AppHarbor.

I want to push to apphb and have it use the correct SLN and ignore the other.

Can this be done?

Updated:

The build error in AppHb is:

**Build failed: Couldn't pick a single solution file to build. Found: \GlennApp\GlennApp.sln and \GlennAppAzure\GlennAppAzure.sln**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this answer in a Support area online.

http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/662-build-failed-couldnt-pick-a-single-solution-file-to-build